# MSI Install Package

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, windows-installer

I'm creating my MSI install package for my Web App and all projects are targeted for .NET 3.5. (in Visual Studio 2010)

Also, I have disabled prerequisite installs when generating the MSI package.

However, when attempting to install on a machine without .NET 4, it asks me if I wanted to install the .NET framework.

Any ideas why? There must be a setting that I am missing.

UPDATE:

I did get this warning, when building the deployment package, will look into this:

WARNING: The target version of the .NET Framework in the project does not match the .NET Framework launch condition version '.NET Framework 4 Client Profile'. Update the version of the .NET Framework launch condition to match the target version of the.NET Framework in the Advanced Compile Options Dialog Box (VB) or the Application Page (C#, F#).

Comment: Which language are coding in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it.

Apparently in the installer project, make sure you also refresh your dependencies and also if you view the properties of "Microsoft .NET Framework", make sure to change it to 3.5. Apparently, it does not change to 3.5 for you, so you'll have to explicitly set it here.

Comment: Please give a better explanation on how you fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MSI installers automatically create the needed references and minimum requirements for the self-installer package. Are sure there is no component within your projects that depends on .NET 4?

Comment: I'm certain. Every project within the solution is targeting 3.5

Comment: I didn't just mean your projects. It could also be any 3rd party resource used within. I'll check into this further on

Comment: Checked ever file, dll, resource. None.

Answer (score 0):

In the installer project you can set installation requirements. You should check that the project hasn't added .NET 4 by default.

Comment: It's added by default, and I have unchecked it. I've even disabled the feature of having it to install prerequisites.